# Show circular indicator while getting the current location in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have trying to get current location with [Location](https://pub.dev/packages/location).when i call the function in button it will ask for enable location but after enable location it take some time to fetch location data instead of that after i press the button a circular indicator should show with in button.This is is what i did.the problem is the circular indicator doesn't show

Submit button

```
 Flexible(
    flex: 0,
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 160),
      child: GestureDetector(
        child: Container(
          height: 60,
          width: double.infinity,
          color: Color.fromRGBO(34, 83, 148, 1),
          child: ProgressButton(),//Progress Widget
        ),
        onTap: () {
          //getLocation function
          _getLocation();
        },
      ),
   ),
 )
```

_getLocation function

```
Future _getLocation() async {
    Location location = new Location();
    LocationData _currentPosition = await location.getLocation();
    

    setState(() {
      SharedPrefrence().setLatitude(_currentPosition.latitude.toString());
      SharedPrefrence().setLongitude(_currentPosition.longitude.toString());
      islocateCompelete = true;
    });

    Future loginstatus = SharedPrefrence().getLogedIn();
    Future gust_status = SharedPrefrence().getGustLogedIn();
    gust_status.then((gustdata) {
     
      loginstatus.then((data) {
       

        if (data == true || gustdata == true) {
          Navigator.pop(context, true);
          Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()),
              ModalRoute.withName("/login"));
        } else {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => LoginScreen(),
            ),
          );
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

ProgressButton Widget

```
 Widget ProgressButton() {
    if (islocateCompelete == true) {
      return Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          CircularProgressIndicator(
              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white)),
        ],
      );
    } else {
      return Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(
            Icons.location_searching,
            color: Colors.white,
            size: 20,
          ),
          Text(
            "Locate Me",
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `setState()` with `isLocateCompelete = false` before you start fetching location.

```
Future _getLocation() async {

    setState(() {
      islocateCompelete = false;
    });

    Location location = new Location();

    var _permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
    if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
      if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        setState(() {
          islocateCompelete = true;
        });
        return;
      }
    }

    LocationData _currentPosition = await location.getLocation();
    
    //...
    //...
    //rest of the code
}
```

Comment: Now it works.but now the problem is when the page opens then ask for permission and enable location but the rest of the code does'nt work.means that when i press the button it starts show loading but rest of code under the setState does't work @Jigar Patel

Comment: @MorbiusBlack Do you mean the rest of the code is not getting executed? This is very unlikely. How did you determine that is not getting executed?

Comment: i mean that after it ask you for permission and enable location and you need to press the button again to run the function to fetch the location it's weird.that what i try to say sorry about that @Jigar Patel

Comment: oh okay I get what you mean. For that you can try to `await` for the permission so after that the rest of the code can be executed. Let me include that part in the answer so you can try. Let me know if it works.

Comment: The code you posted works and i made some changes@Jigar Patel

Comment: Please look into the newly added code i have added enable location service with permission @Jigar Patel